# Is Net::SFTP failing because of SSH?

Tags: perl, ssh, sftp

I have trouble connecting with [Net::SFTP](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSFTP) to a remote server. I ran the same script before on another machine with success, however, I get now the following error:

```
[root@script-server fmzbih_cms_weather_updater]# ./fmzbih_cms_forecast.pl
script-server.bih.net.ba: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
script-server.bih.net.ba: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
script-server.bih.net.ba: Allocated local port 1023.
script-server.bih.net.ba: Connecting to 10.100.4.193, port 22.
script-server.bih.net.ba: Remote protocol version ., remote software version
script-server.bih.net.ba: Net::SSH::Perl Version 1.34, protocol version 1.5.
script-server.bih.net.ba: No compat match: .
script-server.bih.net.ba: Connection established.
Can't locate object method "_session_channel" via package "Net::SSH::Perl::SSH1" at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/Net/SFTP.pm line 78.
```

Could this be because of SSH1 being used as shown in log? Shouldn't SFTP use SSH2?

Comment: use [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::SFTP::Foreign) instead!